# How do I render a render view layer using the command line in Blender 2.8

Tags: render-layers, command-line

It is possible to render using a specific **scene** but I did not see how to select only a **view layer**.

The only solution I found is by unchecking the "Use for Rendering" button for each undesired layers, and save my file.

Any ideas, without Python scripting ?

Something like this would be very useful:

```
blender -b file.blend -S "myScene/myLayer" -f 1
```